# Ну а в сущности(,) мчались мы кольцами

Tags: запятые

Нужна эта запятая в этом отрывке из песни «У дороги нашей любви» в исполнении Боярского?

> Ну а в сущности(,) мчались мы кольцами, / Догоняя всё то, что нас ждёт.

Это же значит 'на самом деле'.

> Ну а на самом деле(,) мчались мы кольцами, / Догоняя всё то, что нас ждёт.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая ставится:

***Ну а в сущности**, мчались мы кольцами, / Догоняя всё то, что нас ждёт.*

**Пояснение**

1. Каждое вводное слово имеет свои **особенности употребления**,  и почти каждый раз приходится отличать вводное сочетание от необособленного обстоятельства (наречия) или частицы. Поэтому обычно **замена** мало что дает для решения задачи.
2. В данном случае важно подчеркнуть, что это **авторское мнение** о каком-либо факте, то есть его **оценка.** Слово  находится в **начале предложения,** и это обычная позиция для вводного слова, когда его удобно **обособить.**

Частица ***НУ*** и присоединительный союз ***А*** обособляется вместе с вводным словом.

[Из справочника Остроумова О.А., Фрамполь О.Д. Трудности русской пунктуации.](https://file:///C:/Users/User/Downloads/104498_edb50bec111d553f5056bb5b92bc0db2.pdf) Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений. Опыт словаря-справочника. М.: Изд-во СГУ, 2009. 502 с

**В СУЩНОСТИ, наречие.**

1. Употребляется в функции **вводного** для выражения
   **субъективного отношения** к какому-либо факту: Город два
   дня, в сущности, был в их руках (Ф.Искандер); Он сам не знал,
   почему он выбрал именно Италию; ему, в сущности, было все
   равно, куда ни ехать -лишь бы не домой (И.Тургенев).
2. **Редко невводное**, употребляется в функции
   **обстоятельства** образа действия (= по сути, реально), не обособляется; норма употребления этого слова как невводного
   является **устаревшей**: Заклинать и оживлять былое я научился
   Бог весть в какие ранние годы - еще тогда, когда в сущности
   никакого былого и не было (В.Набоков);

**В СУЩНОСТИ ГОВОРЯ**, деепричастный оборот.
Употребляется в функции вводного для выражения
**субъективного** отношения к какому-либо факту: В сущности говоря, это была та же фарцовка,только высшего разряда (Ю.Нагибин);